# Docker .exe won't even launch on w10 enterprise

Tags: docker

i have an issue when installing Docker. The .exe didn't want to launch (no error message on double click), i'm only able to install it why command line :

> install --quiet

.

But then, if i'm able to see the service running in my task managment, it is not here un my task bar. 
**I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise v1709.**

If i force install without --quiet, i have this console error message :

> Failed to install: Windows version not compatible.

But my Windows version is clean and updated (hyper-v enable etc...)

It's almost impossible to find any solution after many hours on the problem.
If somebody had any clue :)
Thanks !

Comment: Try to install it using chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker

Comment: Indeed it works for the installation thanks, but still a have nothing that can be launched, if i run docker version i get this

`code`error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`code`

i guess there is another problem on wich i have to work :/

Comment: Its ok now, my .net wasn't update -_-'
Thanks for the help :)